# Add :external to URLs in coffee script

Tags: coffeescript

I have a bit of coffeescript I'm using to add a `:external` pseudo-class to all external links on my site.

```
jQuery.expr[":"].external = (obj) ->
  obj.hostname isnt location.hostname
```

What I want to do is allow exceptions e.g.

```
jQuery.expr[":"].external = (obj) ->
  obj.hostname isnt location.hostname unless obj.hostname is "domain.com" or "sub.domain.com"
```

However this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this jQuery and external thingy, but if the first example is working then you only should return true if you want display as external links, so in your case:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].external = (obj) ->
  obj.hostname not in [location.hostname, 'domain.com', 'sub.domain.com']
```

Comment: One additional question to follow up - could I set a rule that excluded ALL .domain.com subdomains? e.g. *.domain.com - without specifying them all?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `x is a or b` does not test if `x` is either `a` or `b`; you're looking for `x is a or x is b`. This can also be written as `x in [a, b]` which compiles to the same thing anyway.

Secondly the postfix `unless` is a bit unusual. `(a) -> b unless c` compiles to

```
function (a) {
  if (!c) {
    return b;
  }
}
```

so if `c` is true, the function returns `undefined`, which is falsey. So this will work, but I'd find this confusing. The logic is really: a link is external as long as the link destination isn't either `location.hostname`, "domain.com" or "sub.domain.com", i.e.

```
obj.hostname isnt location.hostname and obj.hostname isnt "domain.com" and obj.hostname isnt "sub.domain.com"
```

Which can be written more concisely as

```
obj.hostname not in [location.hostname, "domain.com", "sub.domain.com"]
```

Note that is will also apply the pseudo-class to things where `obj.hostname` is `undefined`, since `undefined` certainly isn't `location.hostname`. This probably isn't what you want. You could use `obj.hostname? and obj.hostname not in [...]` to filter out elements which don't have a `hostname` at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I wanted was to allow all subdomains of my specific domain as exceptions. So - classify links as external BUT if link hrefs are empty, they handle js events, or they point to subdomains of domain.com, do not treat them as external.

```
$.expr[":"].external = (obj) ->
  h = obj.href
  typeof h isnt 'undefined' and h.indexOf('#') is -1 and h.indexOf('javascript') is -1 and h.indexOf('domain.com') is -1
```